# Open existing Google Map infowindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker, infowindow

I am using the Google Map API and I have created a new marker. I can also create and open a new infowindow for that marker, but that I would rather open an infowindow that already exists.

So I have a business location set on the map. When the zoom level is set high enough you can see the business name, and you can click that name and get the infowindow that Google provides. What I would like to do is open that window if someone clicks on my marker that I have placed. Can this be done?

Edit:

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/rob_huska/pen/mOvKXb)

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qy1c6dx8/4/)

```
<div class="acf-map__container">
    <div class="acf-map">
        <div class="marker" data-lat="40.112004" data-lng="-76.02738099999999">I don't want this, I want the window that opens if you click the business name.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
(function($) {

/*
*  new_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function new_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');


    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 17,
        scrollwheel : false,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
    };


    // create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);


    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];


    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });


    // center map
    center_map( map );


    // return
    return map;

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position    : latlng,
            map         : map,
            optimized   : false,
            zIndex      : 1
        });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 ) {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    } else {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/
// global var
var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        // create map
        map = new_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Please put up some code to support your question and a jsfiddle

Comment: added codepen link http://codepen.io/rob_huska/pen/mOvKXb

Comment: and fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/qy1c6dx8/4/

Comment: I forgot to reply to this, after some research there is no way to do as you've asked. The best thing to do is to disable POI clicks on your map and then populate your own Info Window

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. In the maps options I just set this: clickableIcons : false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to disable POI clicks on your map and then populate your own Info Window.